# custom css are applied randomly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I use scss and styled-components together. Recently I don't know why I started to see a race situation over which styles get applied on the final render. Sometimes, usually, when the app is loaded for the first/second time, styles from scss gets applied and when I do a couple of hard refreshes my custom styles written with styled-components get applied. Do you have any idea why is this happening? I don't want to put it! important everywhere to fix it. I would like to understand it.

The below screenshot shows that _sidebar.scss overrode .sidebar styles I wrote.

after some hard refreshes:

[image]

after some refreshes, it is another way around:

[image]

Here is a component

```js
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React from 'react';
import SidebarLinks from './SidebarLinks';
import FormSelectPrinter from "../printer/FormSelectPrinter"
import sidebarData from "../data/";
import {ModalConsumer} from "../components/ModalContext";
import Modal from "../components/Modal";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";


const GlobalSidebarStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    .sidebar {
        background-color: #303b4a;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-bottom:40px;
        width: 240px;
    }

    .user__info {
        background: #607D8B;
    }

    .user__info:hover {
        background: #607D8B;
    }

    .user__name {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .user__email {
        color: #303b4a;
    }
    .dropdown-user-menu {
        background: #607D8B;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }

    .dropdown-select-language {
        background: rgba(96, 125, 139, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        right: -26px;
        top: 53px;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .dropdown-user-item:hover, .dropdown-user-item:focus {
        color: black !important;
    }

    .dropdown-user-item {
        color: white !important;
    }

    .navigation {
        li {
            a {
                color: #adb5bd;
                padding-left: 15px;
                &.active {
                    color: white !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .navigation li:not(.navigation__active):not(.navigation__sub--active) a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        color: white;
    }

    .id-green {
        background-color: #73983F;
    }

    .language-text-color {
        color: white !important;
    }
    .profile_image_style {
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
    }
`

function Sidebar(props) {

    const ModalSelectPrinter = ({onClose, ...otherProps}) => {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <FormSelectPrinter onClose={onClose} md={12}></FormSelectPrinter>
            </Modal>
        )
    };
  

    return (
        <>
        <GlobalSidebarStyle />
        <aside className={`sidebar ${props.sidebarToggled? 'toggled' : ''}`}>
            <div className="scrollbar-inner">
                <div style={{margin: '50px 0 30px 0'}} onClick={() => props.toggleUserInfo()}>
                    <div className={`user__info ${props.userInfoShown? 'show' : ''}`}>
                        <div style={{width: '100%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                            <div className="user__name">{user.person === null ? user.name : user.person.full_name}</div>
                            <div className="user__email">{user.email}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`dropdown-menu dropdown-user-menu ${props.userInfoShown? 'show' : ''}`}>
                        <ModalConsumer>
                            {({showModal}) => (
                                <a className="dropdown-item dropdown-user-item" onClick = {()=>showModal(ModalSelectPrinter, {})}>Select</a>
                            )}
                        </ModalConsumer>
                        <a className="dropdown-item dropdown-user-item" onClick={() => props.logout()}>Log out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <SidebarLinks sidebarData={sidebarData} toggleSidebar={props.toggleSidebar}></SidebarLinks>
            </div>
        </aside>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Where are you invoking the `_sidebar.scss`?

Comment: `import './assets/scss/app.scss';`
`import '../node_modules/material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.css'`; at App.js

Comment: Sorry if not so much clear. App.scss has the _sidebar.scss. and this <Sidebar/> component is rendered at App.js.

Comment: Have you tried styling you component using a *Sidebar.css* file in the same directory and then import it in that manner: `import './Sidebar.css'` ?

Answer (score 0):

In styled-components, createGlobalStyle is a utility function used to create a global style component. Global styles are CSS rules that apply to the entire document rather than being scoped to a specific component. This is useful for defining styles such as body styles, resets, fonts, or other global layout rules.

In your case i wouldn't use that function, but instead have a SCSS file or styled-component object dedicated to the Sidebar component - that would be best practice and allow encapsulation.